# AspNetSqlMembershipProvider asp:PasswordRecovery: How to set the password complexity?

Tags: asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

We are using the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider  control to generate new passwords.

Is there anyway to turn down the complexity of the generated passwords? By default it is outputting things like this: *f.;tp{h|[hPCF

I realize I could roll my own password recovery process if I have to, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all in the web.config. Check out this article, http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/05/11/406550.aspx.

Comment: The suggested answer actually doesn't change the complexity of passwords generated during password reset. They still have the crazy complexity in them. This fix only applies to new user creation or when you call the Membership.GeneratePassword() method. I'm still looking for a solution for the password reset/retrieval part.